# How can I get or download the app built (exe file) from appveyor after finish building

Tags: windows, build, electron, appveyor

I builded an electron app on appveyor, because it uses native node module dependencies.
I needed windows version of that app.
After finishing the build process successfully, I had no idea of getting the exe file.
I think there are some apis or need some cmd on appveyor.yml file to get that. What should I add more after build?
Here is my appveyor.yml file.

```
image: Visual Studio 2017

platform:
  - x64

cache:
  - node_modules
  - '%USERPROFILE%\.electron'

init:
  - git config --global core.autocrlf input

install:
  - ps: Install-Product node 8 x64
  - yarn

build_script:
  - ./node_modules/.bin/electron-builder

test: off
```

please explain in detail as much as possible, I have really no idea of Appveyor.

Comment: Maybe https://www.appveyor.com/docs/appveyor-yml/ can help you, see section about  deployment configuration

Answer (score 1):

You can [package your file as an artifact](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/packaging-artifacts/) and then download it from AppVeyor. However AppVeyor removes artifacts in 6 month after creation according to the [retention policy](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/packaging-artifacts/#artifacts-retention-policy) . Therefore best approach is to [deploy](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/) artifact to a storage of your choice.